# String object is immutable but reference variable is mutable. What does that mean?

Tags: java

I was studying Kathy Sierra Java book. I came across one question something like this:

```
public class A {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        String s1 = "a";
        String s2 = s1;
        //s1=s1+"d";
        System.out.println(s1==s2);
    }
}
```

output: `true`

Two points I didn't understand here are:

1. when I uncomment `s1 = s1 + "d"` output changes to `false`. Same thing happens if I replace String with wrapper `Integer` or `int`.
2. Again, when I change my code to use `StringBuffer` like this:

   ```
   StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("a"); 
   StringBuffer sb2 = sb;
   //sb.append("c");
   System.out.println(sb == sb2);
   ```

   now the output doesn't changes i.e. it remains `true` even if I uncomment the `sb.append`statement.

I can't understand this strange behavior. Can some one explain me.

Comment: `==` tests for object identity.  `s1 = s1 + "d"` makes a new object.  But `sb.append()` doesn't it just calls a method on `sb`.

Comment: Start making a distinction between variables, references, and objects.

Comment: @markspace if `==` is used to check for same memory reference, then why am I getting output `false` if I change String to wrapper class `Double` or `Integer` like this : [this][1][1]: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ducE-yZEDyyjoKUTkTEsw3sdSw740d0Z5iiJz3IzABE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JSK For the *same reason* that `s1 = s1 + "d"` prints false.  *It makes a new object.*

Answer (score 3):

`s2` is a reference to `s1` in the first case. In the second case, `+` is translated to `s1.concat("d")` which creates a new string, so the references `s1` and `s2` point to different string objects.

In the case of `StringBuffer`, the reference never changes. `append` changes the internal structure of the buffer, not the reference to it.

Comment: *"In the second case, + is translated to s1.concat("d") which creates a new string"* I think if you look at the bytecode you'll find it's `StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); sb.append(s1); sb.append("d"); s1 = sb.toString();` But it comes to the same thing: A new string is created.

Comment: Small detail but, in the first case, `s2` is not really a reference to `s1`. Rather, they are both references to the string `"a"`.

Comment: @sstan: Very important distinction.

Comment: @sstan if `==` is used to check for same memory reference, then why am I getting output `false` if I change String to wrapper class `Double` or `Integer` like this : [this][1][1]: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ducE-yZEDyyjoKUTkTEsw3sdSw740d0Z5iiJz3IzABE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @JSK: I added an answer that I hope will help you understand this better.  If something is still unclear, just add a comment under my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Immutable scenario**

The `String` class and wrapper classes like `Integer` and `Double` are all **immutable**.  This means that when you do something like:

```
1. String s1 = "a";
2. s2 = s1;
3. s1 = s1 + "b";
4. System.out.println(s1 == s2); // prints false
```

Notice what really happens under the covers (*very* simplified, and using bogus memory addresses):

1. (line 1) Create a string `"a"` at memory address `0x000001`.
2. (line 1) Set the value of `s1` to `0x000001` so that it effectively points to string `"a"`.
3. (line 2) Copy the value of `s1` and set it to `s2`. So now both `s1` and `s2` have the same value of `0x000001`, and so both point to string `"a"`.
4. (line 3) Find what `s1` is pointing to (string `"a"`), and use that to create a new and distinct string of `"ab"` that will live at a different memory address of `0x000002`. (Note that string `"a"` remains unchanged at memory address `0x000001`).
5. (line 3) Now assign value `0x000002` to variable `s1` so that it now effectively points to this new string `"ab"`.
6. (line 4) Compare the values of `s1` and `s2`, which are now at `0x000002` and `0x000001` respectively. Clearly, they don't have the same values (memory addresses) so the result is `false`.
7. (line 4) Print `false` to the console.

So you see, when changing the `"a"` string to a `"ab"` string, you were not modifying the `"a"` string. Rather, you were creating a 2nd distinct string with the new value of `"ab"`, and then changing a reference variable to point to this newly created string.

The exact same pattern occurs when coding with the other classes like `Integer` or `Double`, which are immutable as well.  You have to understand that when you use operators like `+` or `-` on instances of these classes, you are not modifying the instance in any way. Rather, you are creating a whole new object, and getting a new reference to that new object's memory address that you can then assign to a reference variable.

**Mutable scenario**

This is in complete contrast to **mutable** classes like `StringBuffer` or `StringBuilder`, and others like the unfortunate `java.util.Date`. (BTW, it's best you get in the habit of using `StringBuilder` instead of `StringBuffer`, unless you are using it on purpose for a multi-threaded requirement)

With mutable classes, the exposed methods of these classes ***do*** change (or mutate) the internal state of the object, instead of creating a whole new object. As a result, if you have multiple variables pointing to the same mutable object, if one of those variables is used to access the object and make changes to it, accessing that same object from any of the other variables will ***see*** the changes as well.

So if we take this code, for instance (again, please use `StringBuilder` instead, the net result will be the same):

```
1. StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("a"); 
2. StringBuffer sb2 = sb;
3. sb.append("b");
4. System.out.println(sb == sb2); // prints true
```

Notice how different this is handled internally (again, very simplified, even omitting some details to keep it simple and understandable):

1. (line 1) Create a new `StringBuffer` instance at memory address `0x000001` with an internal state of `"a"`.
2. (line 1) Set the value of `sb` to `0x000001` so that it effectively points to the `StringBuffer` instance, which itself contains `"a"` as part of its state.
3. (line 2) Copy the value of `sb` and set it to `sb2`. So now both `sb` and `sb2` have the same value of `0x000001`, and so both point to the same `StringBuffer` instance.
4. (line 3) Find what `sb` is pointing to (the `StringBuffer` instance), and call the `.append()` method on it to ask it to mutate its state from `"a"` to `"ab"`. (**Very important!!!** Unlike the immutable version, the memory address of `sb` does **NOT** change.  So both `sb` and `sb2` are still pointing to the same `StringBuffer` instance.
5. (line 4) Compare the values of `sb` and `sb2`, which are both still at `0x000001`. This time, they both have the same value, so the result is `true`.
6. (line 4) Print `true` to the console.

**Bonus consideration: `==` vs. `equals()`**

Once you understand the above, then you now have the required knowledge to better understand this peculiar scenario:

```
1. String s1 = "abc";
2. String s2 = new String(s1);
3. System.out.println(s1 == s2); // prints false?!?
4. System.out.println(s1.equals(s2)); // prints true
```

Surprisingly, line 3 returns `false` (?!?). However, once we understand what the `==` operator is comparing, combined with a better understanding of immutable classes like `String`, then it's actually not that hard to understand, and it teaches us a valuable lesson.

So if we do the exercise again of examining what is really happening, we find the following:

1. (line 1) Create string `"abc"` at memory address `0x000001`.
2. (line 1) Set the value of `s1` to `0x000001` so that it effectively points to string `"abc"`.
3. (line 2) Create a new string `"abc"` at memory address `0x000002`. (Note that we now have 2 strings `"abc"`. One at memory address `0x000001`, and the other one at `0x000002`).
4. (line 2) Set the value of `s2` to `0x000002` so that it effectively points to the 2nd string `"abc"`.
5. (line 3) Compare the values of `s1` and `s2`, which are now at `0x000001` and `0x000002` respectively. Clearly, they don't have the same values (memory addresses) so the result is `false`. (Even though they are both pointing to strings that are the same logically speaking, in memory, they are still 2 distinct strings!)
6. (line 3) Print `false` to the console.
7. (line 4) Call `.equals()` on the string pointed to by variable `s1` (address `0x000001`). And as a parameter, pass a reference to the string pointed to by variable `s2` (address `0x000002`). The `equals` method compares the values of both strings, and determines that they are *logically* equal, so it returns `true`.
8. (line 4) Print `true` to the console.

Hopefully, the above now makes sense to you.

And the lesson?

`==` is not the same as `equals()`.

`==` will blindly check to see if the variables' values are the same. In the case of reference variables, the values are memory address locations.  So, even if 2 variables point to logically equivalent objects, if they are different objects in memory, it will return false.

`equals()` is meant to check for *logical* equality.  What that means exactly depends on the specific implementation of the `equals()` method that you invoke. But in general, this is the one that returns the result we expect intuitively, and is the one you want to use when comparing strings to avoid nasty unexpected surprises.

If you need more information, I recommend you do further searches on the topic of immutable vs mutable classes. And also on the topic of value vs. reference variables.

I hope this helps you.